# How to read current sensor values in Tizen native app for wearable (Galaxy Active 2)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I've built a simple watchface for a Samsung Galaxy Active 2 using Tizen Studio, native app.
I have added some of the "health" info to the face: pedometer and heartrate monitor.

Q: I know how to setup a listener and callback so that I can get notified when the heartrate (or step count) **changes**, but I cannot find how to just read the current / last read HRM value. I know this must be possible since other watchfaces do this ... just don't know how.

Code for the listener/callback method:

```
    sensor_get_default_sensor(SENSOR_HRM, &sensor);
    ret = sensor_create_listener(sensor, &hrmSensorListener);
    if( ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "failed to get hrm sensor. err = %d", ret);

    ret = sensor_listener_set_event_cb(hrmSensorListener, 20000, hrm_sensor_callback, face);
    if( ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "failed to set hrm sensor listener. err = %d", ret);

    sensor_listener_set_option(hrmSensorListener, SENSOR_OPTION_DEFAULT);
    sensor_listener_start(hrmSensorListener);
```

This means that when the watchface starts, there is a period when the HRM or step count is not updated, and this is a bit annoying.

How do I read the **current** value of the sensor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try use ***sensor_listener_read_data*** method. According to  [documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html#ga4fb6803008f6f5289b33ae43db521d5b) this method gets sensor data. You may follow [tutorial](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.tutorials/html/native/system/sensor_tutorial_n.htm#event) published on Tizen site.

```
sensor_get_default_sensor(SENSOR_HRM, &sensor);
ret = sensor_create_listener(sensor, &hrmSensorListener);
if( ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "failed to get hrm sensor. err = %d", ret);

ret = sensor_listener_set_event_cb(hrmSensorListener, 20000, hrm_sensor_callback, face);
if( ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "failed to set hrm sensor listener. err = %d", ret);

sensor_listener_set_option(hrmSensorListener, SENSOR_OPTION_DEFAULT);
sensor_listener_start(hrmSensorListener);

sensor_event_s event;
sensor_listener_read_data(hrmSensorListener, &event);
```

I think code above should help you